# Can we use a null instance of a class with a generic-typed property without declaring the Type of that property?

Tags: c#, generics, null

If a class has a property that is of a generic type (Like `Thingus<T>` below), is it possible to use a null instance of that class without specifying the type of the generically-typed property for that object?

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DoThing(new Thingus<int>
        {
            Name = "Integer thingus",
            Something = 42
        });
        
        //Is there a way to make this function work without the function on line 19?
        //If thingus is null then I don't care what the Type is for Something.
        //If not, does the type used in the function on line 19 matter for performance at all?
        DoThing();
    }
    
    public static void DoThing(Thingus<string> thingus = null) => DoThing<string>(thingus);
    
    public static void DoThing<T>(Thingus<T> thingus)
    {
        if(thingus is null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oh look! The thingus is null!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Thingus's Something is {thingus.Something}");
        }
    }
}

public class Thingus<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Something { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The instance being null is separate from the declaration type. You can't declare a reference without specifying the type information or the compiler being able to infer type information. Perhaps you could declare a method that accepts an `object` instead and perform some runtime type checking ...

Comment: So you're saying the function `DoThing` MUST be able to know the Type for the Thingus.Something passed to it so it can do its thing?

I supposed replacing line 19 with `public static void DoThing(Thingus<object> thingus = null) => DoThing<object>(thingus);` works and is more "generic" than using `string`.

Comment: More `DoThing(object obj) { if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) { ... } else if (obj.GetType().Name == "Thingus\`1") { ... } ... }`

Comment: Eh. That's now getting too mechanical for my taste but I see where you're going and if I HAD to do this that seems fine. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

To see why it is probably impossible, consider this code snippet

```
public static void DoThing<T>(Thingus<T> thingus)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
}
```

If you write `DoThing(null)`, there is no hints that which type `T` you want to use, so it is impossible for the compiler to make it works because with just `DoThing(null)` you are providing not enough information for the compiler.

Comment: Yeah this goes along with what @BurnsBA said that the declaration of the function has nothing to do with `thingus` possibly being null. That makes sense.

Why can't the compiler do something like "If an object with a generic property is null, then...."? But I suppose that's the problem the compiler can't handle cuz that answer could be different for every scenario.

Comment: Imagine if the compiler translates from `DoThing(null)` to `DoThing<object>(null)`. The compiler could do that if `where T: class` is specified, but it just doesn't make any sense. Your question is similar to a trivial question that asks why compiler needs us to put semicolon when it knows it is missing. It just wants to make sure your code is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the type parameter on your first call, because the compiler can infer it from the `int` on the type parameter in the argument.  In your second method, it can't infer that, because you want to send `null`.

You can drop the method you want to drop, and call your generic method with some irrelevant type parameter to satisfy the compiler:

```
DoThing<Thingus<int>>(null);
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't see why I need to specify a Type for `T` if I don't actually care abut T's type cuz the whole `Thingus` is null.

Comment: If it came to it, different code could be generated for a method accepting Thingus<T> based on what size T actually is. From this perspective, the T is important even if the actually passed value is null at some point (the same generated code will be reused for additional calls with same T). Since your example can work with object (all you need is ToString), then obviously specifying T is redundant.